# Is it possible to move a slide to a another presentation using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

So I have been working on this for quite a while and I can't seem to make it work. I'm trying to make a script that moves a slide to another presentation using Google Scripts.

I found this script but this one copies only like some elements, not the styles that have in the original copied slide. and it copies every slide from the source presentation.

```
function createCopyUsingSlidesApp() {
 // The Id of the presentation to copy
 var templateId = "1GnuSUbXfk4Ms2IARJam54lNhidVb74UJj-_4TnV22qs";

 // Access the template presentation
 var template = SlidesApp.openById(templateId);
 var fileName = template.getName();
 var templateSlides = template.getSlides();

 // Create a new presentation first
 // (note: SlidesApp does not support a way to create a copy)
 var newDeck = SlidesApp.create("Copy of " + fileName);

 // Remove default slides
 var defaultSlides = newDeck.getSlides();
 defaultSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
   slide.remove();
 });

 // Insert slides from template
 var index = 0;
 templateSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
   var newSlide = newDeck.insertSlide(index);
   var elements = slide.getPageElements();
   elements.forEach(function(element) {
     newSlide.insertPageElement(element);
   });
   //index++;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your showing script, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy all slides from the source Google Slides to a created new Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified.

```js
function createCopyUsingSlidesApp() {
  var templateId = "1GnuSUbXfk4Ms2IARJam54lNhidVb74UJj-_4TnV22qs";
  var template = SlidesApp.openById(templateId);
  var fileName = template.getName();
  var templateSlides = template.getSlides();
  var newDeck = SlidesApp.create("Copy of " + fileName);
  var defaultSlides = newDeck.getSlides();
  defaultSlides.forEach(function (slide) {
    slide.remove();
  });
  templateSlides.forEach(function (slide) {
    newDeck.appendSlide(slide);
  });
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Slides of `templateId` is copied.

```js
function createCopyUsingSlidesApp() {
  var templateId = "1GnuSUbXfk4Ms2IARJam54lNhidVb74UJj-_4TnV22qs";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  file.makeCopy("Copy of " + file.getName(), DriveApp.getRootFolder());
}
```

- In this case, the created Google Slides is put in the root folder with the filename of `"Copy of " + file.getName()`. This is from your showing script.

#### References:

- [appendSlide(slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#appendSlide(Slide))
- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)